# Error deploying NextJs app to Vercel React.Children.only

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I made a nextjs app that I am trying to deploy to Vercel, however when the project builds it throws errors to some of the pages:

```
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
at Object.only (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:19:357)
at LinkComponent (/vercel/path0/devsite/.next/server/chunks/664.js:427:45)
at Wc (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:362)
at Z (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at $c (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at Zc (/vercel/path0/devsite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
```

None of my pages have more than one child element and everything is handled in the tsx file of each respective page (no components). My code can be found [here](https://github.com/alt-f4-software-development/website). The entire log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/x7ziq8S0). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code repo seems to be private. Without looking at the code I can only guess to wrap your component's children components in a React Fragment like so: `<React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>`

Comment: @YashSharma I will try this. The repo is not private I just misspelled the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your element on a fragment like that in link tag on index.tsx

```
<Link
  href="/about"
  className={styles. Card}
 >
  <>
   <h2>About Us &rarr;</h2>
   <p>Learn about us and our services.</p>
  </>
</Link>
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: also you can read this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link